# piglatin positional notation, how to specify an interval

Tags: apache-pig

Lets say I have a very wide data source:

```
big_thing = LOAD 'some_path' using MySpecialLoader;
```

Now I want to generate some smaller thing composed of a subset of big_thing's columns.

```
smaller_thing = FOREACH big_thing GENERATE 
   $21,$22,$23 ...... $257;
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to write out all the columns?

I'm assuming yes but my searches aren't coming up with much, I think I'm just using the wrong terminology.

EDIT:

So it looks like my question is being very misunderstood. Since I'm a Python person I'll give a python analogy.

Say I have an array `l1` which is made up of arrays. So it looks like a grid right? Now I want the array `l2` to be a subset of 'l1`such that`l2' contains a bunch of columns from `l1`. I would do something like this:

```
    l2 = [[l[a],l[b],l[c],l[d]] for l in l1]
    # a,b,c,d are just some constants.
```

In pig this is equivalent to something like:

```
smaller_thing = FOREACH big_thing GENERATE 
   $1,$22,$3,$21;
```

But I have a heck of a lot of columns. And the columns I'm interested in are all sequential and there are a lot of those. Then in python I would do this:

```
l2 = [l[x:y] for l in l2]
#again, x and y are constants, eg x=20, y=180000000. See, lots of stuff I dont want to type out
```

My question is what is the pig equivalent to this?

```
smaller_thing = FOREACH big_thing GENERATE ?????
```

And what about stuff like this:

Python:

```
l2 = [l[x:y]+l[a:b]+[l[b],l[c],l[d]] for l in l2]
```

Pig:

```
smaller_thing = FOREACH big_thing GENERATE ?????
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to do something without having to do it?

Comment: @GoBrewers14: Not at all. Editing my Q now to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in this post: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/08/process-a-million-songs-with-apache-pig/

```
Distanced = FOREACH Different GENERATE artistLat..songPreview, etc;
```

The `..` says use everything from artistLat to songPreview.

The same thing can be done with positional notation. eg `$1..$6`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `you can simply load the dataset without columns`.
But if you load the data with column names will help you to identify the column details in future scripts.

UDF can help you to perform your query, 
For example,

```
REGISTER UDF\path;
a = load 'data' as (a1);
b = foreach a generate UDF.Func(a1,2,4);
```

UDF:

```
    public class col_gen extends EvalFunc<String>
    {

        @Override
        public String exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {

        String data = tuple.get(0).toString();
        int x = (int)tuple.get(1);
        int y = (int)tuple.get(2);
        String[] data3 = data.split(",");
        String data2 = data3[x]+",";
        x = x+1;
        while(x <= y)
        {
            data2 += data3[x]+",";
            x++;
        }
        data2 = data2.substring(0, data2.length()-1);
        return data2;
}
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think my question was misunderstood. I'm editing it now to be more specific

Comment: The above UDF is for the sample one, you may create your own like this